# Custom Repeater Control with Paging and Page Navigation Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create a customer repeater with Paging and accompanying controls e.g. Next Prev buttons.

So far I have the custom repeater with Paged data working fine, and I can get it to render the navigation buttons aswell but I can't assign events to the Navigation LinkButtons.

Here's the Custom Repeater class:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;
using System;

namespace ASPresentation.Controls 
{
[ToolboxData("<cc:PagedRepeater runat=server></cc:PagedRepeater>")]
public class PagedRepeater : Repeater
{
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPageIndex { get; set; }
    public PagedDataSource pagedData = new PagedDataSource();
    LinkButton NextBtn = new LinkButton();
    LinkButton PrevBtn = new LinkButton();

    public bool IsLastPage
    {
        get
        {
            return pagedData.IsLastPage;
        }
    }
    public bool IsFirstPage
    {
        get
        {
            return pagedData.IsFirstPage;
        }
    }

    public override object DataSource
    {
        get
        {
            return base.DataSource;
        }
        set
        {
            pagedData.DataSource = (IEnumerable)value;
        }
    }

    protected void NextButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsLastPage)
        {
            CurrentPageIndex++;
        }
    }

    protected void PrevButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsFirstPage)
        {
            CurrentPageIndex--;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        NextBtn.Text = "Next";
        PrevBtn.Text = "Prev";
        NextBtn.Click += new EventHandler(NextButtonClick);
        PrevBtn.Click += new EventHandler(PrevButtonClick);
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.Controls.Add(PrevBtn);
        base.Controls.Add(NextBtn);
        base.Render(writer);
    }

    public override void DataBind()
    {
        pagedData.AllowPaging = true;
        pagedData.PageSize = PageSize;
        pagedData.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPageIndex;
        base.DataSource = pagedData;
        base.DataBind();
    }
}
}
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: We need to see the repeater and button markup in order to help.

Comment: there isnt any, its all generated in that class.

Comment: What is wrong with the Repeater and other grid options in ASP.NET?  Along with the DataPager control for the pages?

Comment: The data grid is the only of the standard asp.net controls that comes with paging inbuilt and none of them come with the page navigation controls built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making this control a [CompositeControl](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/29/436854.aspx) instead of inheriting from Repeater.  Inside the composite, instantiate your Repeater, PagedDataSource, button controls, and any other controls necessary and add them to the control tree via overriding CreateChildControls.  You can set up your event handlers at this point, too.  Then, [expose the repeater's templates](http://p2p.wrox.com/asp-net-2-0-professional/67647-passing-templates-composite-control.html) in the composite.  I am offering this suggestion as a different approach as you are essentially writing a composite control.  However, you're not adding the buttons to one of the templates of the repeater at render time (say the footer), so you may be losing something.